# Socket.io not starting

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to start socket.io.

It won't start and also does not give me any error messages what so ever. It only shows the prompt sign and that's all.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    client = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(80);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('ferret', function (name, fn) {
    fn('woot');
  });
});
```

Source: http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: Would that give me the same result as the code I posted originally?

Comment: If you changed the 80 to 8080 then yes it would listen on 8080.

Comment: Tried using the following: `var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
 var io = require('socket.io')(8080);

  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
     socket.on('ferret', function (name, fn) {
       fn('woot');
     });
  });` which resulted in an error

Comment: `/var/www/server1.com/public_html/test/chat/server.js:2
        var io = require('socket.io')(8080);
        ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3`

Comment: change it to `var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient, io = require('socket.io')(8080); io.on('connection', function (socket) { socket.on('ferret', function (name, fn) { fn('woot'); }); });` You have an extra `var` in there.

Comment: Unfortunately this does the same as the original code. It stays at the prompt and does nothing

Comment: You haven't defined any output, if you want it to say something you have to code `console.log('connected on port 8080');`

Comment: It should say `info - socket.io started` as described in the tutorial I'm following

Comment: Fixed it. I indeed had to include a `console.log()`. I did not know that the newer versions of socket.io did not show a message at start. Thanks for the help Preston